# Move bottom circle of cylinder to the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am creating cylinder in `canvas`.  Actually cylinder was fine till before when i modified  the x y position of the cylinder. To the left side. I have changed the value in translate in the both functions Now I am confused how to move my bottom to the bottom of the cylinder

Now My bottom circle of cylinder move towards up in the direction.

I have changed the code here:

```
function drawCylinder(x, y, w, h, vRadius, fillStyle, strokeStyle) {
var w2 = w / 2;
var h2 = h / 2;
var ytop = -h2;
var cpYtop = -h2 - vRadius;
var ybottom = h2;
var cpYbottom = h2 + vRadius;
ctx.save();     
ctx.translate(40, 90);  
ctx.beginPath();    
ctx.moveTo(-w2, ytop);  
ctx.bezierCurveTo(-w2, cpYtop, w2, cpYtop, w2, ytop);
ctx.lineTo(w2, ybottom);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(w2, cpYbottom, -w2, cpYbottom, -w2, ybottom);
ctx.closePath();    
performDraw(fillStyle, strokeStyle);    
ctx.restore();  
}
```

and

```
function drawCylinderTop(x, y, w, h, vRadius, fillStyle, strokeStyle) {
var w2 = w / 2;
var h2 = h / 2;
var ytop = -h2;
var cpYtop = -h2 - vRadius;
var cpYLowtop = -h2 + vRadius;
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(40, 90);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(-w2, ytop);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(-w2, cpYtop, w2, cpYtop, w2, ytop);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(w2, cpYLowtop, -w2, cpYLowtop, -w2, ytop);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
performDraw(fillStyle, strokeStyle);
ctx.restore();
}
```

Here is my previous fiddle  [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/rAA8S/10/)

Here is My current fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/py379/)

Kindly help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just had to change the `cx` and `cy` positions:

```
var cx = 40;
var cy = 70;
```

And fix the `drawCylinderTop` translatation:

```
ctx.translate(cx, cy);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rAA8S/12/